# How would one debug a machine learning model that has a bias?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm predicting values roughly forming a normal distribution with mean 0. However, my machine learning model tends to predict lower than 0 on average. I didn't run any statistical tests, but it's very obvious that the prediction distribution doesn't match the training distribution. I tried visualizing the data several ways, the bias was obvious in every visualization.

What are some steps I should do to debug a bias in a machine learning model? I'm using XGBoost.

Edit: Forgot to mention, the actual distribution of the values I'm trying to predict matches the training distribution.

Comment: Why would you expect the conditional distribution of the predicted outcome to match the marginal distribution of the outcome?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the actual distribution of the values I'm trying to predict matches the training distribution.